# Magento 2 Js issue when try to adding to cart

Tags: magento2, cart, javascript, ajax

I receive a js error everytime i try to add products in cart.
I already run all this command but nothing changed :

```
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL
    , magento setup:static-content:deploy, php bin/magento setup:di:compile,  php bin/magento setup:upgrade, php bin/magento cache:clean,  
        php bin/magento cache:flush, bin/magento deploy:mode:set --skip-compilation production
        bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL en_US
        bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant
        rm -Rf var/di/relations.ser
```

I deleted manually all the static files and generation but no result.
I searched for an answer for almost 3 days, and i am running out of ideas.

Here is a print with my js problem: [image: js error]

Can anyone know how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure why, but are you running compile-multi-tenant command ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 500 error according to the screenshot attached. Every time customer/section/load tries to retrieve information about shopping cart from backend server, server returns 500. The only way to check what's wring with this call is to go and check `magentoRoot/var/log/exception.log` file. You will see something like PHP Fatal Error. Also you might want to check `/var/log/apache2/error.log` in case exception.log file is empty.

Updated: please have a look at `magentoRoot/var/log/system.log` file for errors.

For nginx logs please check /var/log/nginx/error.log file.

Let me know what you see so i can advice.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i am using nginx server. where can i found the log?

Comment: i don;t have any err in log files

Comment: any ideas where can i search for answer?

Comment: @AlinLupoiu please have a look at my updated answer